# Convert nested dict to column in Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have data from a json file. I have been able to normalize it to an extent.

I'm wondering if there's an elegant way to convert the remaining data to columns.

I tried to use pd.json_normalize but I get an error on the list in column D.

My next attempt was to separate D and create a Dataframe from the list in D. And normalize each dict individually. And then concat the Dataframes together.

My current issue is that the value of the first key in each dict should be a column name, with the value coming from the key called 'value'. There are five column names across the dicts in column D.

{'key': 'column name', 'value' : 'data value'}

A further complication is that most rows have three dicts, but some have one or two.

I think I could brute force it by swapping the keys and values for the first key in each dict? And then using json_normalise to create columns and values from each dict. But I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way of handling this json data?

I'm trying to turn this:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Value A | Value B | Value c | [{'key': 'column name 1', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 2', 'value' : 'data value'} , {'key': 'column name 3', 'value' : 'data value'} ] |
| 1 | Value A | Value B | Value c | [{'key': 'column name 1', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 2', 'value' : 'data value'} , {'key': 'column name 3', 'value' : 'data value'} ] |
| 2 | Value A | Value B | Value c | [{'key': 'column name 1', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 2', 'value' : 'data value'} , {'key': 'column name 3', 'value' : 'data value'} ] |
| 3 | Value A | Value B | Value c | [{'key': 'column name 1', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 2', 'value' : 'data value'} , {'key': 'column name 3', 'value' : 'data value'} ] |
| 4 | Value A | Value B | Value c | [{'key': 'column name 4', 'value' : 'data value'} ] |
| 5 | Value A | Value B | Value c | [{'key': 'column name 5', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 4', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 2', 'value' : 'data value'} ] |
| 6 | Value A | Value B | Value c | [{'key': 'column name 5', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 4', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 2', 'value' : 'data value'} ] |
| 7 | Value A | Value B | Value c | [{'key': 'column name 5', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 4', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 2', 'value' : 'data value'} ] |
| 8 | Value A | Value B | Value c | [{'key': 'column name 5', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 4', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 2', 'value' : 'data value'} ] |
| 9 | Value A | Value B | Value c | [{'key': 'column name 5', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 4', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 2', 'value' : 'data value'} ] |
| 10 | Value A | Value B | Value c | [{'key': 'column name 5', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 4', 'value' : 'data value'} , {key': 'column name 2', 'value' : 'data value'} ] |

Into:

| A | B | C | D | column name 1 | column name 2 | column name 3 | column name 4 | column name 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Value A | Value B | Value c | data value | data value | data value |  |  |
| 1 | Value A | Value B | Value c | data value | data value | data value |  |  |
| 2 | Value A | Value B | Value c | data value | data value | data value |  |  |
| 3 | Value A | Value B | Value c | data value | data value | data value |  |  |
| 4 | Value A | Value B | Value c |  |  |  | data value |  |
| 5 | Value A | Value B | Value c |  |  |  | data value | data value |
| 6 | Value A | Value B | Value c |  |  |  | data value | data value |
| 7 | Value A | Value B | Value c |  |  |  | data value | data value |
| 8 | Value A | Value B | Value c |  |  |  | data value | data value |
| 9 | Value A | Value B | Value c |  |  |  | data value | data value |
| 10 | Value A | Value B | Value c |  |  |  | data value | data value |

Code:

```
df = pd.read_json(file)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['D'].to_list(),columns = ['list_a','list_b','list_c'])

for column in df2:

    df3 = pd.json_normalize(df[column])
    df = pd.concat([df,df3], axis = 1)
```

Comment: How many columns are you expecting out of Column D ?

Comment: There are five column names across the dicts in column D.

Comment: Can you attach the file to this post ? or provide a link to download the example file?

Comment: What should the expected outcome look like?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've tried to make the input and output clearer

Comment: @itsmrbeltre I have added example data

Comment: @NotationStation I am trying to see if you can simply attach a file containing the Sample data like the one above to understand the formatting and I can provide to you more insides into the issue.  If you can recreate the above in a file. I will try to work on it. It is challenging for me to create a file when it may be completely different than what you expect.l